# Exporting symbology to attribute table using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology, attribute-table, export

I created symbology classes of many polylines in ArcMap 10.2.

I want to know the class that each polyline belongs to (maybe written in a new field on the attribute table? or by exporting the symbology to a document ?).

Is it possible to export the symbology classes to the attribute table to identify which class each polyline I created belongs to ?

Comment: I'm a bit unclear on what you are trying to do. If you've created symbology classes, aren't your classes based on one the attribute table? Or did you individually altered each polyline's symbology, and are trying to write that to the data-table?

Comment: I would like to associate to each polyline the class to which it belongs... In this way, in the attribute table there will be the polyline FIDs, and near a field where it is written which class (for instance 1, 2, 3 ,4 or 5 ...) a given polyline belongs...

Comment: or maybe is it possible to convert each class to a shapefile? for instance I have 5 classes and I want 5 shapefiles...

Answer (score 0):

Add a new column to the datatable, click on all the lines in a class, and then do a field calculate to assign the classname as a value to all of those lines. Repeat for each line class.

Comment: in fact, I would like to know the lines that belong to the different classes. I did a symbology that generally divided the lines into classes. On the map it is possible to identify the classes, but on the attribute table I don't know exactly how the lines are divided ...
I have more than 9000 lines and I can't check one by one...

Comment: I'm unclear how you did a symbology that wasn't class-based, if not manually.

Answer (score 0):

Very similar question was asked before, can't find it. Use below to populate new field in your table:

```
breaks=[0,0.1,0.3,0.6,1]
def Get_Class(x):
 for i,v in enumerate(breaks):
  if  v >= x:break
 return i+1
#---------
Get_Class( !NumericField! )
```

Comment: Thank you but it didn't work ...